# 51Degrees.mobi Foundation Vs WURFL .NET API- which one is better?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need suggestions on 51Degrees.mobi Foundation Vs WURFL .NET API. Which one is better for device detection and redirection?

Please share any article/whitepaper/link/sample etc.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, 51Degrees.mobi uses its own mobile device data files with separate licensing terms: [News article](http://thefonecast.com/News/tabid/62/EntryId/4872/51Degrees-mobi-supports-web-developers-with-new-mobile-device-detection-products.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ScientiaMobile (http://www.scientiamobile.com) is the company behind WURFL and updates the WURFL data file with the latest mobile devices.  The last public snapshot of the data was in June 2011, so unless 51degrees is updating the data file themselves, ScientiaMobile would have  the best/newest information.

Disclaimer:  I work for ScientiaMobile.  Will be happy to answer any questions you have.